# How to load dynamic templates in meteor 0.8 version?

Tags: meteor

I want to **load the templates dynamically without using router package but with session**. 
Functionality is, i have two templates "Register" and "Login". When i click on Login, it must open login page template, same with Register. 
I went through this code to solve, but did not work out.

```html
<body>
    {{> content}}
</body>

<template name="content">
    {{renderTemplate}}
</template>
```

Content Helper

```js
Template.content.helpers({
    'renderTemplate': function(){
        return new Handlebars.SafeString(
            Template[Session.get('currentTemplate')]({dataKey: 'someValue'})
    }
})
```

Please help with solution. Thanks in advance

Comment: I've tried to answer your question but please also provide more detail about the error you are getting.

Answer (score 1):

When you upgraded to 0.8 you should have received a URL to a must-read page. This page tells you that templates are no longer functions and do not return a string:

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Using-Blaze#templatefoo-is-not-a-function-and-does-not-return-a-string

That's why this doesn't work:

```js
Template[Session.get('currentTemplate')]({dataKey: 'someValue'})
```

You can just return the template object., but you will need to somehow change the data context before you call `renderTemplate`. I can't tell you how, since I don't know what all the templates require for their data.

```js
Template.content.helpers({
    'renderTemplate': function(){
        return Template[Session.get('currentTemplate')];
   }
});
```

**Update**:
Make sure to use `{{> renderTemplate}}` as described in the linked page, rather than `{{renderTemplate}}`.

Comment: Yes,We tries to this But it shows `[object Object]`. what we did mistake also didn't get any idea.Please suggest me.@Christian Fritz

Comment: Did you follow the instructions on the page I linked to carefully? Please see update to my answer.

Comment: Yes,I followed update code also but gets same problem.what is the meaning of `change the data context before you call renderTemplate`.@Christian Fritz

Comment: Can you please help me it cames local only but didn't get deployment after.What mistake i did didn't get any idea?.@ Christian Fritz

Comment: I have difficulty understanding your comments. Could you start using punctuation? Also, please update your question with your changes, so I can tell you what you might be doing wrong now.